# How to use w2ui with angular 4? Please share an example

Tags: angular, w2ui

I am trying to use w2ui with angular 4.. tried all possible solutions from web but still facing some or the other issue.
please share an example. it would be really helpful.

Error : core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: $(...).w2grid is not a function

Code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as w2ui from 'w2ui';


import { PartnerService } from '../../services/partner.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-partners',
  templateUrl: './partners.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partners.component.css']
})
export class PartnersComponent implements OnInit {
  partners:Partner[];
  constructor(private partnerService: PartnerService) { 

    if(w2ui.hasOwnProperty('layout')){
        w2ui['layout'].destroy();
    }
    if(w2ui.hasOwnProperty('grid')){
        w2ui['grid'].destroy();
    }
    $('#grid').w2grid({
                name: 'grid',
                show: {
                    footer: true
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: 'fname', caption: 'Date Time', size: '200px',
                        render: function (record, index, column_index) {
                            var html = '<div>'+ record.fname + ' ' + record.lname + '</div>';
                            return html;
                        }
                    },
                    { field: 'email', caption: 'Subsystem', size: '100%' },
                    { field: 'profit',caption: 'ACCES Message Type', size: '120px', render: 'money' }
                ],
                records: 
                [
                        { recid: 1, fname: 'John', lname: 'Doe', email: 'john@gmail.com', profit: 2500},
                        { recid: 2, fname: 'Stuart', lname: 'Motzart', email: 'stuart@gmail.com', profit: 1004},
                        { recid: 3, fname: 'Jin', lname: 'Franson', email: 'jin@gmail.com', profit: 473},
                        { recid: 4, fname: 'Susan', lname: 'Ottie', email: 'susan@gmail.com', profit: 304},
                        { recid: 5, fname: 'Kelly', lname: 'Silver', email: 'kelly@gmail.com', profit: 9300},
                ]
            });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.partnerService.getPartners().subscribe((partners)=>{
        this.partners = partners;        
    });

  }

  supplierInit() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make W2UI available in your component as a JQuery plugin you need to put it in `angular.json` (used to be `.angular-cli.json`) like so:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/w2ui/w2ui.min.js"
      ],
      "styles": [
          "node_modules/w2ui/w2ui.min.css"
        ],
```

This is from Angular documentation: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts#global-scripts

Make sure to add W2UI to your `package.json`:

```
{
    // ...
    "dependencies": {
        // ...
        "w2ui": "^1.4.3"
```

And in your `typings.d.ts` declare `w2ui` and add the plugin to the JQuery interface:

```
// ...
declare var w2ui: any;
interface JQuery {
  w2layout(options?: any): any;
  w2toolbar(options?: any): any;
  w2sidebar(options?: any): any;
}
```

Once this is done, there's no need for

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as w2ui from 'w2ui';
```

in the `component.ts`.